# Subscription status not called for auto renewable subscription in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am facing issues with my auto-renewing subscription for an iOS app that offers auto-renewable subscription. 
The Subscription Status URL is at times, not being called when the subscription is renewed. This is making it difficult for us to track the user's subscription status. Funnily, this behaviour is completely arbitrary at times it is called and everything works smoothly, but at times it is not called at all.

Also, once the user's subscription is renewed, at times the user is not charged on his/her credit card instantly. Is this behaviour normal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow basic rules for subscription based application.

1. Whenever you buy any auto renew subscription, in success verify your receipt and verify expiry date.
2. On every application launch very receipt and verify subscription. On depending result you can notify your server.

In sandbox environment for monthly subscription it will auto renew for every 5 mins. It will auto renew for 5 times. So you can check your test cases. After that it will be expire.

In real world case subscription will auto renew before 24 hours of renew date. So if user cancels subscription before that.

If you are using SwiftyStorekit than it will be very much easy for you to handle each and every steps. Let me know you if you want more coding approach in this case.I will share example code details if you want.

Comment: This is all working fine. The only issue is the server side notification. The subscription status url that apple asks for to update there server from the back end. That is not being called. We are a cross platform app as well, so if that api is not called, and the user logs in from the web instead of the app, we will not be able to get the receipt and verify it.

Answer (score 0):

The Subscription Notifications are pretty unreliable and the descriptions of how they work aren't very clear. For example:

> `RENEWAL` events aren’t sent when a subscription renews. ... `RENEWAL`
>   is sent when a subscription has expired, then later, the user starts
>   the subscription again.
>
> `CANCEL` does not mean a user normally cancelled their subscription. It only is sent when a user cancels their subscription via customer
>   support. This is also known colloquially as a refund.

Source: [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/09/24/apple-subscription-notifications-are-almost-useless) (*Disclaimer: I work there*)